# behat yml extract urlbase to suite level

Tags: selenium, yaml, behat

I have a behat.yml with many profiles. In each profile I have more or lees 10 suites and in these suites I have 10 context and inside this context have a urlbase.

The problem is these urlbase is the same and it's a problem because make a behat.yml very large.

I'm using behat

I would like put de urlbase in the suite level.

Now the behat.yml is like this:

```
profile:
  suite:
     x:
      context1:
        parameters:
           urlbase: url
      context2:
        parameters:
           urlbase: url
      context3:
        parameters:
           urlbase: url
```

Answer (score 0):

What is this `urlbase`? Is it the apps url? Why do you need it in all contexts?